Error code 429 from truecallerjs while doing a search with phone number
I have been trying to follow the guide mentioned in the github project of truecallerjs node library and search a phone number without any success.
Node github project: https://github.com/sumithemmadi/truecallerjs
I have installed the npm package in my node environment that is running in an ubuntu machine. I have logged in using my phone number and otp well and got an installation Id too. But while doing search, I have been constantly getting 429 response code that said "ERR_BAD_REQUEST". Any idea why is this happening? Do I need to register my mobile number somewhere TC portal?
Below is the command and response sample.
truecallerjs -s +91<mobile-number> --json
{
  "message": "Request failed with status code 429",
  "name": "AxiosError",
  "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 429\n    at settle (file:///usr/lib/node_modules/truecallerjs/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (file:///usr/lib/node_modules/truecallerjs/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:589:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:530:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)\n    at Axios.request (file:///usr/lib/node_modules/truecallerjs/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:45:41)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async runCLI (file:///usr/lib/node_modules/truecallerjs/dist/cli.js:236:35)",
  "config": {
    "transitional": {
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "adapter": [
      "xhr",
      "http",
      "fetch"
    ],
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "env": {},
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip",
      "user-agent": "Truecaller/11.75.5 (Android;10)",
      "Authorization": "Bearer a1i08--nlqKNu-5-gztqiQ-NQMDWOIX3XE-lbsYjqub9H1n5bdcClRX9T7KFvmFp"
    },
    "params": {
      "q": "<mobile-number>",
      "countryCode": "IN",
      "type": 4,
      "locAddr": "",
      "placement": "SEARCHRESULTS,HISTORY,DETAILS",
      "encoding": "json"
    },
    "method": "get",
    "url": "https://search5-noneu.truecaller.com/v2/search"
  },
  "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
  "status": 429
}


Expecting an answer please. Have I asked a foolish question?
